# Open edx installation problem

Tags: system-installation

Which Ubuntu versions desktop/server are suitable to install open EDX for educational purposes? and I also  want to edit and test the python code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit the source code and use Ubuntu there's an option describe as:

Native: Automated installation on an Ubuntu machine of your own. Details are on the Native Open edX [Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit Installation page](https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/146440579/Native+Open+edX+Ubuntu+16.04+64+bit+Installation).

Source: https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/OpenOPS/pages/60227779/Open+edX+Installation+Options